# remember <select> on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Can anyone help me with this. I need to remember selected item  on page reload. My code work, but don`t save selected element. Thank you in advance.

```
$(function(){function disableElement(element) {};function getSomething(element, id) {if (id != 0) {

$.ajaxSetup ( {
    url: 'assets/upgraded/configurator.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'action':'load', 'id':parseInt(id)}
});
$.ajax ( {
    success: function(messages) {
        var messages = JSON.parse(messages);
        if (messages.length > 0) {
            for (var i=0; i < messages.length; i ++) {
                $(element).append('<option value="' + messages[i].id + '">' + messages[i].pagetitle+ '</option>');
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Ошибка загрузки: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError);
    }
});
$(element).prop('disabled', false); } else {disableElement(element);}}; getSomething('#mark','1');

$('#mark').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    getSomething('#model',id);
    disableElement('#year');
    disableElement('#engine');  
});
$('#model').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    getSomething('#year',id);
    disableElement('#engine');
});
$('#year').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    getSomething('#engine',id);
});});
```

Comment: You could use local storage to remember informations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store whatever value you want to use. That can be done in many ways. As @Sushil mentioned, [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) is a choice. [HTML5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is another one, and yet, even a database is useful to persist data.

But you can keep your `<select>` option in browsers cache or something like that.

Tell me if I understood your question properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use cookie to store the selected element value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: hi Ben, the reason i chose to provide the answer was that I didn't have sufficient reputation to comment. i know this does not answer the question but it at-least gives him a direction.